# Quick way to find the GCD of 7602 and 7710

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I've been reading through my book and I see that to find the GCD of these two numbers, I can look at the difference of these two numbers. However, how do I determine the GCD from the difference? I've got that $7710 - 7602 = 108$. And $108$ is $2^2 * 3^3$.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you refer to the remainder? Euclide's algorithm?

Comment: So, are the numbers divisible by $2$? By $4$? By $3$, by $9$, by $27$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Euclid's Algorithm?

Comment: It is true the a common divisor of 7602 and 7710 will be a divisor of their difference.  You have made progress, but you need to narrow it down some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you found the difference $108=2^2\cdot 3^3$, you can use the divisibility tests to find out that $7602$ is:

- divisible by $2$, as it ends in $0$
- not divisible by $4$, as it ends in $10$
- divisible by $3$, since the sum of digits is $15$
- not divisible by $9$, by the previous item.

So, $6$ is the greatest divisor of $180$ that also divides  $7602$.

Comment: Thank you. Only question I have is what would be the point of figuring out the difference if I just use the divisibility rules? Only reason I'm specifically asking about the difference is because he mentioned it in today's lecture.

Comment: The difference is much smaller than either of two numbers. This made it possible to factor it completely. Then only these  factors  need to be checked. This is why I did not have to check divisibility by 5, 7, 11, 13 and so on.

Comment: Thank you. One last question. Is there a reason we stop at 9? Why not check 54 or 27 (they both divide 108)?

Comment: If a number is not divisible by 9, it's not going to be divisible by 27, because 9 divides 27. The system is this: for every prime factor (such as 2 or 3) we look for the highest power that divides both numbers. Then the GCD is the product of such highest powers. From 108 I know that only 2 and 3 should be considered, no other prime factors are present. Check $2^1$... works, $2^2$... fails. Then $3^1$... works, $3^2$... fails. Answer: GCD is $2^1\cdot 3^1$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So I'm supposed to determine the prime factorization of a number and check the highest powers of each prime? Also, doesnt 2 to the of 2 work for 108 (27 x 4)? Or am i checking 2 to power of 2 for 7602?

Comment: The power of a prime has to divide both numbers. Equivalently, it has to divide one of the numbers *and* their difference. The difference is understood: only $2$ and $3$ are in play, with powers $2$ for each. Then I look at what works for one of the numbers (does not matter which one): as you see in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

By Euclide's Algorithm we have
$$\gcd(7710,7602)=\gcd(108,7602)=\gcd(108,70\times108+42)=\gcd(108,42)=\gcd(2\times42+24,42)=\gcd(24,42)=\gcd(24,18)=\gcd(6,18)=6$$

Comment: Thank you, but is there a simpler way? This was a 2 point question on my exam and was meant to be a quick question according to my professor.

Comment: If it was meant to be quick, then use a calculator.

Comment: He doesn't allow the use calculators either. =/